Given a Hecke character on an imaginary quadratic field, what are its values on non-principal ideals?
Let $\chi$ be a Hecke character of an imaginary quadratic field $K$ of conductor $\mathfrak{f}$ over the field of rational numbers. By a Hecke character $\chi$, we mean a group homomorphism
$$
\chi: I(\mathfrak{f}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times},
$$
where $I(\mathfrak{f})$ is the group of fractional ideals of the ring of integer $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ that is coprime to $\mathfrak{f}$. Then for any principal ideal $(\alpha) \in I(\mathfrak{f})$, we know that
$$
\chi((\alpha)) = \chi_{\infty}(\alpha) \chi^{\infty}(\alpha),
$$
where $\chi_{\infty}(\alpha) = \alpha^{a} \bar{\alpha}^{b}$ for some integer $a,b$ independent of $\alpha$ (called the infinite type of $\chi$) and $\chi^{\infty}: (\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{f})^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a group homomorphism (called the finite type of $\chi$).
My question is: Now that we have fully understood the value of $\chi$ on principal ideals (that are coprime to the conductor $\mathfrak{f}$), what about its values on non-principal ideals of $K$?

My naive attempt: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a non-principal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$, then $\mathfrak{a}^{h} = (\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_{K}$, where $h$ is the class number of $K$. Then $\chi(\mathfrak{a})^{h} = \chi((\alpha))$. Therefore, we know $\chi(\mathfrak{a})$ is an $h$-th root of $\chi((\alpha))$, with $\chi((\alpha))$ we know clearly.
BUT: I get stuck at determining which $h$-th root of $\chi((\alpha))$ is the value $\chi(\mathfrak{a})$. It seems that it does not make sense to write directly
$$
\chi(\mathfrak{a}) = \chi((\alpha))^{1/n},
$$
because we have to a priori choose a certain $h$-th root of $\chi((\alpha))$. In the post "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501818/hecke-characters-of-imaginary-quadratic-fields", the answer of Heiko said that we can take any $n$-th root of unity, but it does not seems to be reasonable to me, because it is then hard to verify that $\chi(\mathfrak{ab}) = \chi(\mathfrak{a})\chi(\mathfrak{b})$ with the ambiguity that the $h$-th roots remain unchosen.
It confused me a lot, though it might be an easy question at first glance. Thank you all for paying attention, commenting or answering! :)

The principal ideals relatively prime to $\mathfrak f$ are a subgroup with finite index in the group of all fractional ideals that are relatively prime to $\mathfrak f$. Show that when $G$ is an abelian group and $H$ is a subgroup with finite index, each homomorphism $\chi : H \to S^1$ extends in $[G:H]$ ways to a homomorphism $G \to S^1$.
